# Have the inverse operation of ‘stereoRectify’ in OPENCV?

Tags: opencv

Firstly, 'stereorectify' have already done based on binocular vision, and then the image matching calculation is made with the corrected image. The matching points of the left and right images have been generated. Now it is necessary to restore the coordinates of the matching points to the coordinates before the image rectify. How can I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXpAu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find "initInverseRectificationMap()"in OPENCV 4.5.3,[enter link description here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga0ee548cb0101533abba06cd89c75b53e)
And I make a test to compare the image after 'stereorectify' with the image after 'InverseRectification' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHnWG.png),the two images are not on the same horizontal line
In addition, I compare the image without 'stereorectify' with the image after 'InverseRectification'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtJGO.png),the two images are parallel on a horizontal line
so,"initInverseRectificationMap()" worked.
but it works on the image type,how it works on "Point2f"?